# C- how to stop Repeating one more time in while roop (I'm beginner)

Tags: c

I am writing a currency conversion program by C.

This is how the program should work:

1. user entered the character in the option lists(A~C)
2. program prints the amount of converted money and should ask the options unless the user inputs other characters not in the option lists.

2-1. if the user inputs other characters that are not in the options list, the program asks the user to input the correct characters.
3. if the user inputs 'C', the program is quitted.

However, when I execute the codes, here's how it works.

1. the program prints the amount of converted money depend on the option.

**2. the program enters to 2-1 though I did not input any characters.**

3. the program re-asks to input the character and option.

I do not want my program to perform second step. How can I fix it?

```
float Conversion(float AmountInWon, float rate);
void menu(void);
int AskChoice(void);
char choice= ' ';
float amount=0;
float rate=0;

int main(void)
{
    
    while(choice!='C'){
        printmenu();
        choice=AskChoice();

    if(choice=='A'){
            printf("Enter the amount in option: ");
            scanf("%f",&amount);
            rate=0.000905;
            printf("%f Won equals to :%f Dollar\n",amount,CurrencyConversion(amount,rate));
            choice=' ';
        }
        else if(choice=='B'){
            printf("Enter the amount in option: ");
            scanf("%f",&amount);
            rate=0.000807350908;
            printf("%f Won equals to :%f Euro\n",amount,CurrencyConversion(amount,rate));
            choice=' ';
        }

        else if(choice!='C'){
            printf("You entered invalid input. Please input correct number\n");
            printf("\n");
            choice=' ';
        } 
    printf("You quit thi, thank you for using.\n");
  }  
}
```

Comment: `else if (choice == 'C') { printf("You quit this program, thank you for using my program\n"); break; }`??

Comment: Please make this a [mcve] with *all* the code necessary to test the program.  The bug could be in `AskChoice()`.

Comment: What does AskCoince do?  I think it probably uses getchar to get the choice?  getchar leaves the newline in the buffer and then when you ask again you get the newline character.  If that's what you are doing, sure you call getchar() or something similar after each input to eat the newline still in the buffer.

Comment: Try using switch statements along with do while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would be very helpful but you should start your program this way, using [getchar](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar):

```c
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    while((c = getchar()) !='C'){ // will take user's input and compare it with 'C'
        printmenu();
    }
 // get user input again
    if(choice=='A'){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line in while loop and ask to user Q or q to quite the program

```
else if(choice=='Q' || choice =='q'){
            beack;
        }
```